# How to take advantage of the Move Semantics for a better performance in C++11?

Tags: performance, c++11, move-constructor, move-assignment-operator

After many trials I still do not understand how to properly take advantage of the move semantics in order to not copy the result of the operation and just use the pointer, or std::move, to "exchange" the data pointed to. This will be very usefull to speed-up more complicated functions like f(g(),h(i(l,m),n(),p(q()))
The objective is to have:

```
t3={2,4,6}; 
t1={}; // empty
```

While executing the code below the output is:

```
t3={2,4,6};
t1={1,2,3};
```

Code:

```
namespace MTensor {

 typedef std::vector<double> Tensor1DType;

 class Tensor1D {
  private:
    //std::shared_ptr<Tensor1DType> data = std::make_shared<Tensor1DType>();
    Tensor1DType * data = new Tensor1DType;
  public:
    Tensor1D() {
  };
  Tensor1D(const Tensor1D& other) {
    for(int i=0;i<other.data->size();i++) {
      data->push_back(other.data->at(i));
    }
  }
  Tensor1D(Tensor1D&& other) : data(std::move(other.data)) {
    other.data = nullptr;
  }
  ~Tensor1D() {
    delete data;
  };
  int size() {
    return data->size();
  };
  void insert(double value) {
    data->push_back(value);
  }
  void insert(const std::initializer_list<double>&  valuesList) {
    for(auto value : valuesList) {
      data->push_back(value);
    }
  }
  double operator() (int i) {
    if(i>data->size()) {
      std::cout << "index must be within vector dimension" << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    return data->at(i);
  }
  Tensor1D& operator=(Tensor1D&& other)  {
    if (this == &other){
      return *this;
    }
    data = other.data;
    other.data = nullptr;
    return *this;
  }
  void printTensor(Tensor1DType info) {
    for(int i=0;i<info.size();i++) {
      std::cout << info.at(i) << "," << std::endl;
    }
  }
  void printTensor() {
    for(int i=0;i<data->size();i++) {
      std::cout << data->at(i) << "," << std::endl;
    }
  }
};
} // end of namespace MTensor
```

In file main.cpp:

```
MTensor::Tensor1D scalarProduct1D(MTensor::Tensor1D t1, double scalar) {
  MTensor::Tensor1D tensor;
    for(int i=0;i<t1.size();++i) {
      tensor.insert(t1(i) * scalar);
    }
  //return std::move(tensor);
  return tensor;
}

int main() {
  MTensor::Tensor1D t1;
  t1.insert({1,2,3});
  std::cout << "t1:" << std::endl;
  t1.printTensor();
  MTensor::Tensor1D t3(scalarProduct1D(t1,2));
  std::cout << "t3:" << std::endl;
  t3.printTensor();
  std::cout << "t1:" << std::endl;
  t1.printTensor();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no `t3` or `t1` in your code - please post a [MCVE].

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html.

Comment: Sorry... I just added the remaining code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `new` is a red flag, especially on a `std::vector`.

`std::vector`s support move semantics natively.  They are a memory management class.  Manual memory management of a memory management class is a BIG red flag.

Follow the rule of 0.  `=default` your move constructor, move assignment, copy constructor, destructor and copy assignment.  Remove the `*` from the vector.  Don't allocate it.  Replace `data->` with `data.`

The second thing you should do is change:

```
MTensor::Tensor1D scalarProduct1D(MTensor::Tensor1D t1, double scalar) {
```

As it stands you take the first argument by value.  That is great.

But once you take it by value, you should reuse it!  Return `t1` instead of creating a new temporary and returning it.

For that to be efficient, you will want to have a way to modify a tensor in-place.

```
void set(int i, double v) {
  if(i>data->size()) {
    std::cout << "index must be within vector dimension" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  data.at(i) = v;
}
```

which gives us:

```
MTensor::Tensor1D scalarProduct1D(MTensor::Tensor1D t1, double scalar) {
  for(int i=0;i<t1.size();++i) {
    ts.set(i, t1(i) * scalar);
  }
  return t1; // implicitly moved
}
```

We are now getting close.

The final thing you have to do is this:

```
MTensor::Tensor1D t3(scalarProduct1D(std::move(t1),2));
```

to move the `t1` into the `scalarProduct1D`.

A final problem with your code is that you use `at` **and** you check bounds.  `at`'s purpose is to check bounds.  If you use `at`, don't check bounds (do so with a try/catch).  If you check bounds, use `[]`.

End result:

```
typedef std::vector<double> Tensor1DType;

class Tensor1D {
private:
  //std::shared_ptr<Tensor1DType> data = std::make_shared<Tensor1DType>();
  Tensor1DType data;
public:
  Tensor1D() {};
  Tensor1D(const Tensor1D& other)=default;
  Tensor1D(Tensor1D&& other)=default;
  ~Tensor1D()=default;
  Tensor1D& operator=(Tensor1D&& other)=default; 
  Tensor1D& operator=(Tensor1D const& other)=default; 
  Tensor1D(const std::initializer_list<double>&  valuesList) {
    insert(valuesList);
  }
  int size() const {
    return data.size();
  };
  void insert(double value) {
    data.push_back(value);
  }
  void insert(const std::initializer_list<double>&  valuesList) {
    data.insert( data.end(), valuesList.begin(), valuesList.end() );
  }
  double operator() (int i) const {
    if(i>data.size()) {
      std::cout << "index must be within vector dimension" << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    return data[i];
  }
  void set(int i, double v) {
    if(i>data->size()) {
      std::cout << "index must be within vector dimension" << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    data.at(i) = v;
  }
  static void printTensor(Tensor1DType const& info) {
    for(double e : info) {
      std::cout << e << "," << std::endl;
    }
  }
  void printTensor() const {
    printTensor(data);
  }
};

MTensor::Tensor1D scalarProduct1D(MTensor::Tensor1D t1, double scalar) {
  for(int i=0;i<t1.size();++i) {
    t1.set(i, t1(i) * scalar);
  }
  return t1;
}



int main() {
  MTensor::Tensor1D t1 = {1,2,3};
  std::cout << "t1:" << std::endl;
  t1.printTensor();
  MTensor::Tensor1D t3(scalarProduct1D(std::move(t1),2));
  std::cout << "t3:" << std::endl;
  t3.printTensor();
  std::cout << "t1:" << std::endl;
  t1.printTensor();
  return 0;
}
```

with a few other minor fixes (like using range-for, DRY, etc).

Comment: Thank you @Yakk Actually even if I didn't know that manually handling pointers to vectors is a dangerous stuff , - but could you,please, explain us why? -, I do started in searching for a solution without pointers to vector...ending nowhere. Your valuable suggestions and hints do actually work just perfect!!!. Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: @user2315094 It is akin to putting a modern car onto a hand-made at-home car to drive around.  `vector` is a type that manages memory.  That is its job.  It is an industrial-quality memory management type.  You are now manually managing `vector` itself.  That is the hand-made at-home car you are now placing the fancy factory-made car on top of. The car can already drive around, but you have placed it on a *worse* chassy and driving that around... for no good reason. "DRY" is "Don't Repeat Yourself"; in code, repeating something attracts bugs (and if you do fixes, you risk fixing it in 1 place)

Comment: Thank you very much Yakk for your kind help and explanations. Marco

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `t1` when calling `scalarProduct1D`, otherwise you'll make a copy:

```
MTensor::Tensor1D t3(scalarProduct1D(std::move(t1),2));
```

You need to explicitly use `std::move` because `t1` is an *lvalue* expression.

Note that you'll have to fix your printing functions to avoid dereferencing `nullptr` if you want accessing the moved-from object to be a valid operation. I instead suggest to avoid making method invocation on moved-from objects valid as it requires additional checks and doesn't follow the idea of *"this object has been moved, now it's in an invalid state"*.

[**live wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RH4mkznzY275Fugl)

Comment: Hi Vittorio Romeo doing this: MTensor::Tensor1D t3(scalarProduct1D(std::move(t1),2)); the output is:t3:
2,
4,
6,
t1:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @user2315094: yes, because you're dereferencing `nullptr` in `printTensor`. You should not use `t1` after moving it.

Comment: That leaves `t1` a bad state. I don't think the OP should do that. You should move an object only when it is not going to be use at all after it is moved.

Comment: @RSahu: look at the OP's objective. He is expecting that `t1` becomes "empty" after moving it, but he wasn't actually moving it in `main`. After moving it, the objective could be achieved by simply checking for `nullptr` in `printTensor`, but I instead suggest to avoid accessing `t1` altogether after moving it.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, I think the OP needs something like `MTensor::Tensor1D t3(std::move(scalarProduct1D(t1,2)));`. They want to move the *result of the operation*.

Comment: @RSahu: that doesn't make sense. `scalarProduct1D` returns a local variable by value. `scalarProduct1D(whatever)` is an *rvalue* expression, and it will implicitly call the move constructor when used to construct `t3`.

Comment: Ok... I do understand that after moving t1 I cannot use it anymore because the pointer is made nullptr... anyway putting the MoveConstructor in this way:     Tensor1D(Tensor1D&& other) : data(std::move(other.data)) {
      //other.data = nullptr;
    }
doesn't change the result: 0,
0,
0,
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @user2315094: because now you have two objects storing the same `data` pointer, and you get double-`delete` *(which is UB)*. You should think about what's happening and look for more resources on *move semantics* online instead of going by trial-and-error. There are many good questions on StackOverflow and articles that can be easily found that cover what *move semantics* are and how they work.

Comment: Ok. doing this, which I actually think as more logic:   //MTensor::Tensor1D t3(scalarProduct1D(std::move(t1),2));
  MTensor::Tensor1D t3(std::move(scalarProduct1D(t1,2))); the output is: t3:
2,
4,
6,
t1:
1,
2,
3,
does it mean that it copies instead "moving"?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, I thought so too. But it doesn't.http://ideone.com/ECgcQf.

Comment: @RSahu: that's calling the copy constructor for the `t1` function parameter. The move is simply being elided. Proof: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5944d1cdcac422e6 *(compiled with `-fno-elide-constructors`)*

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, that makes sense now. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Does it make sense according to you?                                                    void printTensor() {
      if(data!=nullptr) {
        int dataSize=data->size();
        for(int i=0;i<dataSize;i++) {
          std::cout << data->at(i) << "," << std::endl;
        }
      }
      else {
        std::cout << "data is a nullptr" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
      }
    }

Comment: @user2315094: in my honest opinion you should simply assert that `data != nullptr`, and document the fact that calling `printTensor` on a moved-from object is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Should I put the CopyConstructor as =delete  in order to not interfere with the MoveConstructor?

Comment: I put in this way:     void printTensor() {
      if(data!=nullptr) {   // printing     }
    else {
        std::cout << "data is a nullptr" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
      }
}

Comment: @user2315094: only if you want your class to be move-only. Please read some resources onto the subject or create new questions / a question on CodeReview.se if you have further doubts.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much for both of you for your kind help.

Comment: @user2315094: you're welcome. Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted if you feel like it answer your original question.

Comment: I'm just looking at your github's explanations about C++11...I need to learn as much as possible

Comment: @VittorioRomeo After reading your github explanations about smart pointers, I substituted the "raw" pointer with a unique_ptr:  class Tensor1D {
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<Tensor1DType> data{new Tensor1DType};
   Tensor1D(Tensor1D&& other) : data(std::move(other.data)) {
    }

    ~Tensor1D() {
      //delete data;
    };